# Dynamically assign values to select tag using Xquery

Tags: html, xquery, html-select, marklogic

I tried drop down using

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

It is working well. Instead of **hard-coded** values , I would like to dynamically assign values from another `xquery/xpath`

Example

```
/leader/country/text()
```

So I will have list of countries from the above code that should go to select tag of **HTML**

Comment: This makes sense, except you haven't asked a question.

Comment: How to pass values from "/leader/country/text()" to HTML tag Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an XQuery FLWOR expression like:

```
<select>{
  for $country in /leader/country/string(.)
  return <option value="{$country}">{$country}</option>
}</select>
```

While XPaths over the database are useful for getting started, it's good to learn the Search API or cts:search() to query with good performance over large datasets.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks ! ..it is working .. i changed "of" to "in" in your code

Comment: Thanks for seeing through the JavaScriptism -- fixed now.